# When exactly should I repartition my dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I'm working with a large Spark application on EMR that processes data in the hundreds of GBs. At the moment, I'm reading in a number of parquet files that are transformed into Spark dataframes and subsequently performing data enrichment.

During this step, I'm joining several of these dataframes together in order to compute intermediate values or derive new columns from existing ones. As I'm learning more about Spark, it's become obvious to me as this job continues to scale that I need to be mindful of potential performance optimizations.

After looking into the Spark UI for my application, I notice that a number of my executors are not getting input and there is seemingly skew in the shuffle reads and writes

[image]

There is an ID key in my dataframes that I am joining on that should be evenly distributed so it makes me feel like I need to repartition my dataframes upon reading them in from the original parquet files. Is this line of thinking correct? Should I be calling repartition manually on my dataframe on that ID key, or is Spark already handling this and what I am seeing above is actually a symptom of something else?

Thanks!